# Marionette.js - Uncaught ReferenceError: text is not defined

Tags: javascript, backbone.js, marionette

I wonder if someone can help to find what's wrong in this case. I get "Uncaught ReferenceError: text is not defined" in line 6 app.js:

```
((__t=( text ))==null?'':_.escape(__t))+
```

**driver.js:**

```
var Marionette = require('backbone.marionette');
var TodoView = require('./views/layout');

var initialData = {
  items: [
    {assignee: 'Scott', text: 'Write a book about Marionette'},
    {assignee: 'Andrew', text: 'Do some coding'}
  ]
};


var App = new Marionette.Application({
  onStart: function(options) {
    var todo = new TodoView({
      collection: new Backbone.Collection(options.initialData.items),
      model: new ToDoModel()
    });
    todo.render();
    todo.triggerMethod('show');
  }
});

App.start({initialData: initialData});
```

**views/layout.js**

```
var Backbone = require('backbone');
var Marionette = require('backbone.marionette');
var ToDoModel = require('../models/todo');

var FormView = require('./form');
var ListView = require('./list');


var Layout = Marionette.View.extend({
  el: '#app-hook',

  template: require('../templates/layout.html'),

  regions: {
    form: '.form',
    list: '.list'
  },

  collectionEvents: {
    add: 'itemAdded'
  },

  onShow: function() {
    var formView = new FormView({model: this.model});
    var listView = new ListView({collection: this.collection});

    this.showChildView('form', formView);
    this.showChildView('list', listView);
  },

  onChildviewAddTodoItem: function(child) {
    this.model.set({
      assignee: child.ui.assignee.val(),
      text: child.ui.text.val()
    }, {validate: true});

    var items = this.model.pick('assignee', 'text');
    this.collection.add(items);
  },

  itemAdded: function() {
    this.model.set({
      assignee: '',
      text: ''
    });
  }
});

module.exports = Layout;
```

**todoitem.html**

```
<%- item.text %> &mdash; <%- item.assignee %>
```

Any can me explain why text is not defined?

Comment: it looks like an underscore's template error. It probably means that you're using something like `<%= text %>` somewhere in a html template and that you're not passing the right data to the compiled template.

Comment: I updated question: added template itemlist.html with output.

Answer (score 1):

check your ToDoModel for a typo, the Backbone Model field should be "defaults" not "default", while parsing for a template Marionette view looks for "defaults" field:

https://marionettejs.com/docs/master/template.html#rendering-a-model

so the ToDoModel code should go like this:

```js
...

var ToDo = Backbone.Model.extend({
    defaults: {
        assignee: '',
        text: ''
    },
    
...
```

Answer (score 0):

You should take a look at the Marionnette's [ItemView documentation](http://marionettejs.com/docs/v2.4.7/marionette.itemview.html#itemview-render) which explain how to render a template with custom data.

> ```
> var my_template_html = '<div><%= args.name %></div>'
> var MyView = Marionette.ItemView.extend({
>   template : function(serialized_model) {
>     var name = serialized_model.name;
>     return _.template(my_template_html)({
>         name : name,
>         some_custom_attribute : some_custom_key
>     });
>   }
> });
>
> new MyView().render();
> ```
>
> Note that using a template function allows passing custom arguments
>   into the `.template` function and allows for more control over how the
>   `.template` function is called.

With the code you provided at the moment, I can't help.

Comment: You can try with the templateHelper of the ItemView, a function that will run every render and you dont want to be part of your model

Answer (score 0):

Marionette calls 'serializeModel' before passing the context to 'template'. So, if you have a backbone.model like

```
{
    .
    .
    .
    attributes: {
        text: 'someText',
        asignee: 'someAsignee'
    }
    .
    .
}
```

your template will receive

```
{
    text: 'someText',
    assignee: 'someAsignee'
}
```

I have worked with handlebars but not underscore exactly. There `{{this.text}}` and `{{this.assignee}}` works like a charm in the template. So, try `this.text` or `text` in place of `item.text`, see if that works